# Show Custom Field in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created with custom plugin 2 new fields at user profile.
Now I want to show them when a user login the values.
I write a function in theme but I cant figure out how to call it.
How I can do this?

In `function.php`

```
function my_extra_author_fields( $user ) { 
    $registered_date = get_the_author_meta( 'registered_date', $user->ID );
    $expiry_date = get_the_author_meta( 'expiry_date', $user->ID );
?>
    <h3>My Fields</h3>

    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="registered_date">Registered date</label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="date" name="registered_date" id="registered_date" class="regular-text" value="<?php esc_attr( $registered_date ); ?>" />
                <br />
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <th><label for="expiry_date">Expiry date</label></th>
            <td>
                 <input type="date" name="expiry_date" id="expiry_date" class="regular-text" value="<?php esc_attr($expiry_date); ?>" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php }

add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'my_extra_author_fields' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `get_user_meta()` like this:

`$registered_date = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'registered_date' , true );`

More information: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/

Comment: I’m not sure I follow. Didn’t you want to retrieve user meta in the function you posted as part of your question? Or are you not sure where to add your action + function?